# Get Future objects from Future Options in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, future, playframework-2.3, scala-option

I am new to Scala from Java so the functional programming thing is still a bit difficult for me to understand. I have a project in Play framework. I need to query the database to get rows with ids and display them in a html template.

Here is my code

```
 def search(query: String) = Action.async{ request =>
    val result = SearchEngine.searchResult(query)
    val docs = result.map(DocumentService.getDocumentByID(_).map(doc => doc))
    val futures = Future.sequence(docs)
    futures.map{documents =>
      Ok(views.html.results(documents.flatten))
    }
  }
```

`getDocumentByID` returns a `Future[Options[Document]]` object, but my `results` template takes `Array[Document]` so I have tried to no avail to transform the `Future[Options[Document]]` to `Array[Document]`

The current code I have is the closest I have been, but it still does not compile. This is the error:

```
Error:(36, -1) Play 2 Compiler: 
    found   : Array[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[models.Document]]]
    required: M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to `collect` only the `Some`s from the Future returned by the `getDocumentByID`

```
val docs = result.map { res =>
  val f: Future[Option[Document]] = DocumentService.getDocumentByID(res)
  f.collect { case Some(doc) => doc } 
}.toList

val futures = Future.seqence(docs) //notice that docs is converted to list from array in the previous line
```

General suggestion

Do not use `Array`s. Arrays are mutable and they do not grow dynamically.
So it is advisable to avoid using Array in concurrent/parallel code.

Comment: I have just done that but there is error in `Ok(views.html.results(documents.flatten))` line. It says:                  `type mismatch, expected: Array[Document], actual: Array[Nothing]`

Comment: @Ken remove  `flatten`

Comment: When I remove it there is still error: `Type mismatch, expected: Array[Document], actual: mutable.ArrayOps[Document]`

Comment: @ken what is the type of the `documents`

Comment: `documents` is just a variable used in the `map` construct

Comment: I did `documents.toArray` and there are no longer errors but during compilation this error still appears:`Error:(36, -1) Play 2 Compiler: 
    found   : Array[scala.concurrent.Future[Option[models.Document]]]
    required: M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]]` on the line `val futures = Future.sequence(docs)`

Comment: @Ken edited the answer. Please check with above given code

Comment: I have tried that too and there is an improvement but there is still an error: `Error:(36, -1) Play 2 Compiler: found : Array[scala.concurrent.Future[models.Document]] required: M[scala.concurrent.Future[A]] on the line val futures = Future.sequence(docs)`        It seems that the `Future.sequence()` expects a `Monad` and not `Array`

Comment: @Ken what is the return type of search results

Comment: and int array `Array[Int]`

Comment: @Ken ... Hey got it. Edited the code. Please check.  Notice the `toList` at the end

Comment: @Ken `Future.sequence(docs)` gives compilation error when `docs` is Array. convert the docs to List. Use my code in the above answer.

Comment: @Ken List is also Traversable

Comment: @Ken ... When ever you want to get rid of Option inside List or Future or Some type. You can use collect

Comment: @Ken do not forget to upvote and accept the answer :)

Comment: you're a live saver, I've been stuck with this the whole day, thanks a lot, I have upvoted it but unfortunately it is not showing because I'm a newbie. I just registered this evening. I had an account before but I was blocked from asking questions today, I have probably asked many stupid questions:)

Comment: @Ken you can accept the answer. By clicking at the tick mark at the left irrespective of your reputation/upvotes

Comment: BTW, the `f.collect { case Some(doc) => doc } ` doesn't handle `None` case and the resulting future will be failed